# How to go about sketching this subset of $R^2$

Tags: graphing-functions

If we let $X = \{(x,y) \in R^2 : |x| + |y| \ge 1, \max\{|x|,|y|\} \le 1\}$ how would I go about sketching this subset, I am having some trouble getting started.

Comment: Do you know how to sketch each individual subset $\{(x,y) : |x| + |y| \ge 1\}$ and $\{(x,y) : \max\{|x|, |y|\} \le 1\}$?

Comment: A good start would be to plot the associated equalities, such as $|x|+|y|=1$. This will make it easier to tackle inequalities as a next step, since the equalities usually give the boundaries for the inequalities. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The curves $\max\{|x|,|y|\} = 1$ and $|x| + |y| = 1$ will form the boundary of the region that you're trying to sketch.  You should find that both of these curves are squares in the $xy$-plane (though the second is a "tilted" square).